# Python Django and Celery periodictasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a personal website that I want to track the price of bitcoin but I want the code to run every five minutes in the back end of the website.

I am very new to Celery so I do not know much of what I am doing. That being said, I have updated my installed_apps, I have imported djcelery and I have done all of the updates to the settings page.

I set up a periodic task through the admin website because it looked pretty straight forward but I have been unable to run the code automatically despite my function being an option as a task.

I am pretty stuck here and any help would be awesome. Thanks.

```
def bitcoin():
    url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
    request = Request(url)
    response = urlopen(request)
    the_page = response.read()
    data = json.loads(the_page)
    btc_price = data['bpi']['USD']['rate']
    print('According to CoinDesk, the price of bitcoin is: ' + 
    str(btc_price))
```

Comment: What is the expected result? There's no django or celery code in your question. Both django and celery are non-trivial to configure and run. If all you want to do is run a scheduled task, there are simpler options for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the Django celery [cron schedules](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) documentation which has a couple examples of creating scheduled tasks.

Below is a trivial example from their docs:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```